# Can't see data in SQL Server database table

Tags: sql-server

I can't see data in SQL Server database table. The column is of `nvarchar(MAX) not null`.

It stores json string in string format.

When I run query `Select * from table`, I can see the data in output window, but can't see when I open table using edit top 200 rows.

Comment: Which tool do you use to run the statement?

Comment: running query in new query window option of SQL server 2014

Comment: SQL Server has no "query window" - which SQL _tool_  do you use?

Comment: Screenshots (or a more detailed description of exactly what you're doing) would be helpful. It sounds like you're carrying out both of these actions in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)? One being executing the query `SELECT * FROM table` and the other being right-clicking on that table in the Object Explorer and selecting `Edit Top 200 Rows`? If so, can you confirm that your query editor window and your connection within the Object Explorer are to the exact same SQL Server instance, using the same credentials?

Comment: @3N1GM4...yes I'm doing it in SSMS..credentials are same & same SQL Server instance..

Comment: @PratikPatani which SSMS version did you use? Are you using the latest one? And what do you mean `can't see when I open table using edit top 200 rows.` ? That the column doesn't appear? Are you sure it isn't a limitation of the version you use?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to the latest version. This problem occurs if you use SSMS v. SQL 2008 for working with SQL server 2014.